# Keep getting 'None of ... are in the [columns]' error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\DiegoRocco\Downloads\clientes.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
today = datetime.date.today()
df['Situação'] = ['Pagamento não-pendente' if not df[df['Data de Vencimento']] == today else 'Pagamento pendente']
print(df)
```

So, I want to import an Excel file with the columns ('Nome','Telefone' and 'Data de Vencimento') and then create a new column ('Situação') based on the values from the 'Data de Vencimento' column. The thing is: if the value from 'Data de Vencimento' is equal to the current date in my computer, the value from 'Situação' will be 'Pagamento não-pendente, otherwise it will be 'Pagamento pendente'. However when I try to do so, I keep getting the error message previously mentioned.
I tried to use df.loc[df['Nomes'] == ' '] = np.nan (np = numpy), since I thought the empty spaces could be a problem, but it didn't work neither.

Comment: Voting to close, please add an [mre].

Answer (score 1):

In line 7 of your code, you are trying to assign a list to a pandas column and that would throw an error. You can achieve your result in several ways - I have listed a couple of methods below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\DiegoRocco\Downloads\clientes.xlsx', sheet_name='my_sheet')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
today = datetime.date.today()

# method one
df['Situação'] = np.where(df['Data de Vencimento'] == today, 'Pagamento não-pendente', 'Pagamento pendente')

# method two
df['Situação'] = df['Data de Vencimento'].apply(lambda x: 'Pagamento não-pendente' if x == today else 'Pagamento pendente')

print(df)
```

Hard to help you without any error traceback. Line 4 of your code doesn't specify a sheet_name which could also be causing a trivial issue.

Comment: So, I keep getting this:

Comment: raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

Comment: KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2023-12-31', '2023-12-31', '2023-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Can you show us the traceback? It'll help identify the issue.

Comment: Any chance you can show us what your dataframe contains (samples)?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, my conditional statement was incorrect and the different data types were messing my code, but everything is fine now.